# Spring @RequestMapping "produces" tag is used for what purpose

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I Did one POC using "produces" tag of `@RequestMapping`, I am not getting why this tag is used for? 
The Doc Says:

> You can narrow the primary mapping by specifying a list of producible
>   media types. **The request will be matched only if the Accept request
>   header matches one of these values.** Furthermore, use of the produces
>   condition ensures the actual content type used to generate the
>   response respects the media types specified in the produces condition.

When I used it in my application and when I call the service without setting Accept request header also I can access the service, Narrowing means what here?

```
@RequestMapping(value="/public/login",
                method=RequestMethod.POST,
                produces="application/json")
public @ResponseBody LoginResponse loginUser(@RequestBody LoginEvent loginEvent) {
        return null;

}
```

I am not getting the reason why its used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
produces="application/json"
```

means that your method will produce json as a result, and it will be sent in response.

Answer (score 3):

Not sending an `Accept` header is equivalent to accepting everything. And if you only have one method mapped to `/public/login` then there is no need to narrow anything so the method will always match.

But Spring would not know what format the response should be and it would choose the next best one, so to speak. `produces="application/json"` ensures that JSON is chosen as output format.

Comment: Browsers and API tools (like postman) sends a default Accept header `*/*` and that is the reason why spring matches the wildcard header to the `produces` parameter.